Spring Boot 3.2.7, Java 17: Migration issue with Timestamp filed used in query
I have Entity class where I have
private Timestamp startDate;private Timestamp endDate;
field which is mapped to start_date, end_date -> timestamp with time zone  in PostgreSQL table.
After updating from Spring boot 2.7.18, Java 11 to 3.2.7, Java 17
I am getting error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.sql.Timestamp' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
How I can fix it?
Query I have is
 @Query("SELECT cn FROM CnEntity cn WHERE cn.isActive = true AND cn.startDate < now() And cn.endDate > now() ORDER by cn.endDate ASC)

Are your TimeStamp properties annotated with @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) ?

Shouldn't that be private OffsetDateTime startDate;...? I think so

Do you have a Postgres driver as a separate dependency?

@g00se yes, I have this
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


Use only java.time classes. Avoid the tragically flawed legacy date-time classes such as Timestamp, Date, Date, Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, etc.

That at least is the latest driver. I would search this site using that exception message. There will be more than one hit

Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-temporal
The mappings have changed,  and you may want to use either OffsetDateTime or ZonedDateTime instead of Timestamp.
The doc says:

Applying @Temporal to java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp
or any of the java.time types is considered an exception


btw, the reason I cited OffsetDateTime above and not ZonedDateTime is that most RDBMSs play fast and loose with the term 'timezone' on the whole. iirc PG is no exception and what they actually mean is 'timestamp with offset from UTC'. The analog for that is OffsetDateTime

@g00se with OffsetDateTime I get


I'm sorry - I guess it wasn't obvious. My point is a general one and not offered as a solution to your current problem

To be clear: JDBC 4.2 and later maps the SQL Standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to the Java class java.time.OffsetDateTime.

Try to replace now() by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
@Query("SELECT cn FROM CnEntity cn WHERE cn.isActive = true AND cn.startDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP And cn.endDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER by cn.endDate ASC)

